# JavaScript: How many unique characters the string contains?

Tags: javascript

Given a string in the range **a-z** .  Get the minimum number of characters in string, that are unique. If we have a string **`dabbcabcd`** , the minimum number here will **4** , since those list of characters are not the same **'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'**.
Here is what I have tired

```
let output = [];
function fewestCoins(coins) {
for(let i = 0; i< coins.length; i++){
    if(coins[i] === coins[i+1]){
      output.push(coins[i])
    } else console.log(coins[i])
 }
}

let str = 'dabbcabcd';

fewestCoins(str);
```

Comment: So what you mean is the number of unique characters. In that case, `new Set(str).size`. Done.

Comment: "*characters that not repeat*" is rather misleading. The question is asking how many unique characters the string contains.

Comment: @Bergi yes, that I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Set` from the string and get its size, as `Set`s only contain unique values.

```js
function fewestCoins(coins) {
  return new Set(coins).size;
}
let str = 'dabbcabcd';
console.log(fewestCoins(str));
```

Comment: Why `[...coins]`? Just `new Set(coins).size` will work as the parameter can be any iterable

Comment: @adiga Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach it takes the number of the keys as a metric

```js
function fewestCoins(str) {
  g={}
  str=str.toLowerCase()
    for (let char of str) {
      g[char]=0
    }
      return Object.keys(g).length
  }
  console.log(fewestCoins('dabbcabcd'));
```